# mysql select single column as single dimension array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I'm selecting a single column from my mysql database:

```
$savedSQL = 'SELECT can_id FROM savedsearches WHERE user_id = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($user_id).'" AND insertTime >= "'.$lastSigTime.'"';
$savedQuery = mysql_query($savedSQL);
```

And I'd like to return the values as a single dimension, enumerated array such that array[0] = row1, array[1] = row2, etc.

When I put it into an array like this:

```
while($savedResult = mysql_fetch_array($savedQuery))
    {   $savedArray[] = $savedResult;   }
```

It returns it as a multi-dimension array so that array[0][0] = row1, array[1][0] = row2, etc.

I was thinking of adding something like this:

```
while($i=0;$i<count($savedArray);$i++)
{
 $newSavedArray[$i] = $savedArray[$i][0]
}
```

But is there an easier, more efficient way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're very close.  You just need to access `$savedResult[0]` to retrieve your column, and append it onto `$savedArray`

```
while($savedResult = mysql_fetch_array($savedQuery)) {
  $savedArray[] = $savedResult[0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while($savedResult = mysql_fetch_array($savedQuery)) {   
     $savedArray[] = $savedResult['can_id'];   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$savedArray[] = $savedResult['can_id'];
```

instead of

```
$savedArray[] = $savedResult;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method with mysqli and no loop. It takes all your code down to only two lines.

```
$r = mysqli_query($c,'SELECT can_id FROM savedsearches WHERE user_id = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($user_id).'" AND insertTime >= "'.$lastSigTime.'"');
$savedArray = array_column(mysqli_fetch_all($r,MYSQLI_ASSOC),"can_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you initially get the results of mysql you can merge the contents of both while loops into one:

```
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($savedQuery)) {
    $savedArray[] = $result[0]; // or $result['can_id']
}
```